# Clickable table updated remotely android

Tags: android, database

I want to create a clickable table, which is updated remotely. I think to use fusion table, you have any suggestions on how to make this app for Android?

Please help me.

Comment: i think you need to add some details here....where is the table to click and update?  Is it an Android SQlite table to be updated from some other place or  Fusion table on a server somewhere else that needs to be updated?

Comment: I want a table on the app and that each cell must be clickable. The content within the cell must be read from a database that is updated remotely. Is better sqlite or fusiontable?

Answer (score 0):

As fusion is not supported natively on Android, SQLite is your choice - unless you like pain and suffering